# Testing ElasticSearch with Node. Force update index after populating MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mocha.js

I'm populating MongoDB and adding [river-mongodb](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) in a before hook in my tests. But it looks like Elasticsearch hasn't indexed the data I have in MongoDB when I query it. 
Am I doing it wrong, or should I force an update somehow?

```
  function setupMongoDBRiver() {
      var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta';
      var requestData = {
          "type": "mongodb",
          "mongodb": {
              "db": "harvester-test",
              "collection": "entries"
          },
          "index": {
              "name": "harvester-test",
              "type": "entries"
          }
      };
      request({
          url: url,
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
      },
  }



 describe('Entries Test Parameters', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        DatabaseHelper.restoreAll(mongoUrl, done);
        deleteTestIndex();
        setupMongoDBRiver();
        testQuery();  
       // ^ curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/harvester-test/entries/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*
    }
```

**testQuery** Does not return what I put in MongoDB. Could be that ES needs more time to index the data?
Do I have to specify the ES index, or is that taken care of by river-mongodb?

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note about your `before()` function which seem to suggest that you haven't fully grasped how asynchronous function calling works on Node.

Let me walk through the steps:

```
  DatabaseHelper.restoreAll(mongoUrl, done);
```

I assume that this function resets or restores your MongoDB to a predefined state. You're calling Mocha's `done` callback when it has finished (which signals to Mocha that the `before()` is finished), yet continue to call other functions. You should call `done` when *everything* is ready, not just the first function.

```
  deleteTestIndex();
  setupMongoDBRiver();
  testQuery();
```

These are all asynchronous functions. In other words, you need to explicitly wait for their completion before continuing on to the next step (you *first* want to delete the test index, *then* set up the MongoDB river, *then* run the test query).

A good module to coordinate asynchronous functions is [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async). You can use [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) (or perhaps [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)) to coordinate your function calls, but it would require some rewriting (for instance, your `setupMongoDBRiver()` function doesn't call a completion callback).

Assuming that you rewrite your code to use completion callbacks, your `before()` would look something similar to this:

```
before(function(done) {
  async.series([
    function(next) {
      DatabaseHelper.restoreAll(mongoUrl, next);
    },
    function(next) {
      deleteTestIndex(next);
    },
    function(next) {
      setupMongoDBRiver(next);
    },
    function(next) {
      testQuery(next);
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    done();
  });
});
```

(NB: this can be written more concisely but I used verbose notation for clarity)